# replaceing a toggle switch for EXHAUST fan for small bathroom with a rocker switch

Tags: wiring, exhaust-fan

I have a bathroom with two separate toggle switches; one for the light and one for the exhaust fan. I have updated the light switch with a dimmer/motion sensor rocker style switch. Now, my question is: Can i replace the toggle style switch to the exhaust fan with a rocker style switch? Do you use the same rocker style switch as one would use if it were for a light or is there a special type of rocker switch for an exhaust fan vs a light ? And what amp rating do I use: 15 or 20 ? Does it matter if the rocker switch is rated for more amps than it needs?

Comment: If you're upgrading anyway, consider installing a timer switch.  That way you can run the fan long enough after your shower, to remove all the moisture.   Just make sure you get a device rated for inductive loads.

Answer (score 2):

A simple on/off switch is best for a fan. This is a 'single-pole' switch. For a rocker style, something like this would work

http://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-Decora-15-Amp-Single-Pole-AC-Quiet-Switch-White-R72-05601-2WS/100058788

The switch will most likely be rated for 15 amps. This is fine, the switch must be the same as or more than the fan.